# ironpython IDE supporting intellisense for user library

Tags: ironpython, intellisense

I'm trying the VS2010 ironpython extension and the Pydev. 
Both of them support intellisense for .net library, but neither seems support for custom .net library. 
Is there any IronPython IDE which support intellisense for custom .net library?

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately need to add the library into your project for it to be picked up via intellisense.  If you are working w/ just loose files (no solution) then you should be able to just open a file from the library and the full library should be analyzed.

Comment: I suspect I have a similar problem; is it possible to have intellisense autocompletion for an external custom library with no sources?  (provided that intellisense works for it in a C# code).